# Retrive contact list from iPhone and display in presonal app

Tags: ios4

Can somebody give me an idea of how to retrieve the first and last names from an iPhone contact list and show them in a personal app? In the iPhone contact list, some people have 100 contacts and I want to retrieve the first name and last name from those 100 contacts and display them in my app.

Does anybody have any idea how to retrieve from the contact list and display in my app?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this method to sync iPhone device contact information in your own applicaiton and can display in your own list.

Here you can use one Array - "contactArray" to store the contact information.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    contactArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self SyncContactData];

    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**This is the method to sync contact information from device to applicaiton.**

```
- (void) SyncContactData
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

    for( int i = 0 ; i < nPeople ; i++ )
    {
        dicContact = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i );

        if(ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty) != nil || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)] length] == 0)
            [dicContact setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)] forKey:@"firstname"];
        else
            [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"firstname"];

        if(ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty) != nil || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty)] length] == 0)   
            [dicContact setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty)] forKey:@"lastname"];
        else
            [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"lastname"];

        if(ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonOrganizationProperty) != nil || [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonOrganizationProperty)] length] == 0)   
            [dicContact setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonOrganizationProperty)] forKey:@"name"];
        else
            [dicContact setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[dicContact valueForKey:@"firstname"],[dicContact valueForKey:@"lastname"]] forKey:@"name"];

        NSData *data1 = [(NSData *) ABPersonCopyImageData(ref) autorelease];

        if(data1 == nil)
            [dicContact setObject:@"" forKey:@"image"];
        else
            [dicContact setObject:data1 forKey:@"image"];

        multival = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonAddressProperty);
        NSArray *arrayAddress = (NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(multival);
        if([arrayAddress count] > 0)
        {
            if([[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"City"] != nil)
                [dicContact setValue:[[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"City"] forKey:@"city"];
            else
                [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"city"];

            if([[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"State"] != nil)
                [dicContact setValue:[[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"State"] forKey:@"state"];
            else
                [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"state"];

            if([[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Street"] != nil)
                [dicContact setValue:[[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Street"] forKey:@"address1"];
            else
                [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"address1"];

            if([[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"ZIP"] != nil)
                [dicContact setValue:[[arrayAddress objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"ZIP"] forKey:@"postcode"];
            else
                [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"postcode"];
        }
        else
        {
            [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"city"];
            [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"address1"];
            [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"state"];
            [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"postcode"];
        }

        multival = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        NSArray *arrayPhone = (NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(multival);
        if([arrayPhone count] > 0)
            [dicContact setValue:[arrayPhone objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"telephone"];
        else
            [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"telephone"];

        multival = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        NSArray *arrayEmail = (NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(multival);
        if([arrayEmail count])
            [dicContact setValue:[arrayEmail objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"email"];
        else
            [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"email"];

        multival = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonURLProperty);
        NSArray *arrayURL = (NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(multival);
        if([arrayURL count])
            [dicContact setValue:[arrayURL objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"website"];
        else
            [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"website"];

        [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"address2"];
        [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"mobile"];
        [dicContact setValue:@"" forKey:@"fax"];
        [dicContact setValue:@"1.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000" forKey:@"color"];

        [contactArray addObject:dicContact];
        [dicContact release];
    }

    CFRelease(addressBook);
    CFRelease(allPeople);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this sample application, QuickContacts, in the iOS documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

It is intended as an introduction to working with the Address Book Framework, the full documentation for which you can find [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007212). This framework provides a number of useful functions for working with contacts.